# How to monitor Apache httpd webserver & angular application using ELK

Tags: angular, apache, elasticsearch, monitoring

I am performance testing a web application in which I am getting "proxy server failed to respond due to upstream server error" to monitor this. i want to install ELK

Technical details

- Webserver - Apache https
- Appserver - Angular

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.